# Relation between half smash and smash product

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Let $X$ be a pointed space with base point $x_0$ and $B$ be an unpointed space. Define the half smash product between $X$ and $B$ mas follows:

$$B \ltimes X:= \frac{B \times X}{B \times \{x_0\}}$$

Now consider space $B_+ = B \coprod \{+\}$, ie $B$ with an additional point $+$. So, we can think $B_+$ as a pointed space with base point $+.$ Then the smash product is $B_+ \wedge X = \frac{B_+ \times X}{B_+ \vee X}$

Statement: The spaces $B \ltimes X$ and $B_+ \wedge X$ are homotopic.

Is the above statement is true? If true can you suggest any reference?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Reference: check out John Harper's book Secondary Cohomology Operations

Comment: You could perhaps point to the specific page where the result in proven in this book.

Comment: After checking, this result isn't actually proven there. The half -smash is given as definition 3.3.1 and this result is just stated. However, there is still information in and around this definition that the OP will probably find useful to understanding the definition. I probably should have posted this as a comment...

Answer (score 1):

The spaces $B_+ \wedge X$ and $B \rtimes X$ are the same space... If you want to be very pedantic they are homeomorphic.

$B_+ \times X = B \times X \sqcup \{pt\} \times X$, and you are collapsing $B_+ \vee X = B \times \{pt\} \cup \{pt\} \times X$ to a point. That gives us precisely $(B \times X)/(B \times pt)$